# Using SQLAlchemy how do you change the default value for a column?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Let's say we have a simple model-

```
class Project(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode(255), nullable=False, server_default=u'', unique=True)
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, server_default='0')
```

What would the command be to change the `active` column's default from '0' to '1'?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SQLAlchemy doesn't support this. Instead I used alembic with the following line:

```
op.alter_column('project', 'active', server_default='1')
```